# Execute command in a remote server with PHP

Tags: php, unix, exec, server, remote-server

I have a web page written in PHP and I'm trying to execute an array of commands against a remote server. When running these commands, I need to run them on another machine so I can pass through the firewall.

The general idea of what I can looking for is to execute the output of this in a remote server

```
foreach ($filter as $filtered) {
    echo './script_to_execute_in_a_remote_server '.$filtered
}
```

So, for example, I would be executing the following on the remote server

```
./script_to_execute_in_a_remote_server.sh attribute1 attribute2
```

And I connect to the intermediate server using SSH, connecting to the firewall

```
 ssh root@firewall;
```

From there I connect to the remote server using SSH (this time from the firewall)

```
ssh root@server1;
```

And once I've finally connected to the remote server over SSH, that's when I execute the commands I printed out before

```
./script_to_execute_in_a_remote_server.sh attribute1 attribute2
```

What is the best way that I can do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: Does your current version not work? Or are you interested in optimizing it?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks a lot for your response! I understand how to use ssh2-exec, but not how to pass a command through a firewall and then to the server (two connections).

Webserver with php webpage ---> firewall ---> server where I want to execute the command from my php code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question has a lot of moving parts to it, but you've defined it fairly well. I've reworded quite a bit of it to make the execution flow a bit more clear, as well as move the core question to the end (so people know what "this" is). The only thing I would recommend is to add some code that you have tried using, and ask a specific question about why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've connected to the firewall via php ssh2, you can pass a regular cli ssh command via the PHP ssh2 session.

```
ssh root@server1 ./script_to_execute_in_a_remote_server.sh attribute1 attribute2
```

Sending this command will tell the firewall to connect to server1, execute that command, then disconnect once it's done.